# jquery CONTAINS:text

Tags: php, jquery, html

As seen in my code below:
this is in header part called by

```
<input type="text" size="30" onkeyup="filter(this.value)" />
```

--

```
function filter(a){

               if (a.length > 0)
                    {$("tr").hide();
                    $("tr:contains('"+a+"')").show();}
               else
                    {$("tr").show();     }
}
```

I have list of items in Table format wherein there are 3 TD, Item Code, Item Desc, Item Type

I have an input box that I would like to filter out the Table by matching the text inputted in the textboxt to match it in the Item Code Only, not in the whole TR.

How do I search Only in  but hide the whole  if it doesnt match the search? This is to filter my table to the one being typed.

HTML TABLE generated from my SQL Select

http://jsfiddle.net/zs4Tz/

Comment: If you only want to look at the contents of a specific `<td>` element then we need a way to select that specific element, can we see the HTML for the table?

Comment: i tried using this..  http://jsfiddle.net/zs4Tz/ but failed to run it properly.. the code i pasted was running fine in me

Comment: @AnthonyGrist did you see my HTML table from the fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Try with following:

```
$("td:contains("+ a +")").parent('tr').show();
```

OR

```
$('td').filter(function() {
  return $.trim( $(this).text() ) == a;
}).parent('tr').show();
```

Comment: @Sid try with my update solution, if not work them make a fiddle and share that link. IT would be more better if you share you `table` mark-up to get better solution

Comment: Both of these use **any** `<td>` element in the row, whereas the question seems to indicate he only wants to check the value of a specific `<td>` element in the row.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist yup, I added that to comment